# How to say "tricks" in Chinese? As in "Snowboarding Tricks"?

Tags: translation

I looked it up and a lot of words that mean "trick" come back so I'm sure which is the right one.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is 花招 or [耍花招](http://www.zdic.net/c/d/e6/230873.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Question Overflow made a good point.

招式 is often used for 'tricks' in sports like skateboarding - so in theory it should work with snowboarding just the same. You can even shorten it to just 招 if you'd like -- might sound a bit kung-foo-y though...

edit: some extra info:

see this [article](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_68254bb20100spfw.html)

the article talks, mainly, about ski + snowboard tricks the article features the word 招式 a lot：
`等你熟练起跳跟着陆之后，可以开始最基本的招式。`

`在雪地上尝试招式前，你可以先在干地上练习。`

etc etc

Answer (score 1):

`Tricks` here means 'maneuvers performed for fun or for show in a sports game'. It's translated into `花样动作` or `花式动作` in Chinese.

Sports games for the exhibition of tricks is called `花样xx` or `花式xx`.

E.g. `freestyle snowboarding` is `花样滑雪`, `figure skating` is `花样滑冰`, `exhibition basketball` is `花式篮球`, etc.

Comment: Okay, so would snowboarding tricks be: 滑雪板运动的花样?

Comment: @Taylor It would be 花样滑雪动作 or 滑雪中的花样动作.

Comment: @Taylor I would go for "滑雪板花式".

Answer (score 1):

In your context, "技巧" is a candidate.

Comment: 准确！As OP said *"a lot of words that mean "trick""*, but within the given context, "技巧" is the perfect translation.